# Get number of RAM channels as a property of the system

Tags: windows, wmi, hardware

I've found the WMI [Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) class which has an **InterleaveDataDepth** property. However, this is given per RAM stick, while the property is a system property, unlike **InterleavePosition**.

So I was wondering where is the **InterleaveDataDepth** property found ***as a property of the computer*** instead of of a RAM stick.

Comment: This may be better posted at [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: You can remove the C++ tag, as you didn't mention any language in your post.